# Ссылка на скачивание

Tags: html

Всем салют! Писал уже три раза, еще раз напишу:
Как сделать ссылку на скачивание приложения для андроида, а именно: поставить картинку на саит и туда (неведомым мне пока образом) запихнуть ссылку на скачивание приложения, чтоб когда навел на нее курсор - она подсветилась, юзер нажал на неё и пошла закачка приложения? Спасибо за ответы!

Comment: точно так же, как и любой другой файл скачать.    
к Андроиду эти ни как не относится

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте сервис [DroidBin](http://www.droidbin.com/) (требуется ожидание 30 секунд для незарегистрированных) или [APKHosting](http://apkhosting.com/) (его не пробовал).

Только что перечитал ваш вопрос: просто закачиваете ваш APK на хостинг с поддержкой прямых ссылок (например, [MediaFire](http://mediafire.com/)), а потом просто встраиваете код на вашу страницу:

```
<a href="прямая ссылка на приложение"><img src="иконка"></a>
```

И потом по нажатию на картинку начнётся скачивание.